# When I split a large post with <!--nextpage-->, how can a search locate users to the correct page?

Tags: pages, search

I have a large post split with `<!-- nextpage -->`. A term resides on page 50. When I search for the term, I land on page#1.

**Q:** How can the system auto-forward me to page#50?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

*UPDATE:* After I needed this myself, I reworked it completely.

### The Goal

I wanted to point every `get_permalink()` call directly to the paged post page - without any exception. At least this is the function used by nearly every other function that needs to link somewhere, so it imo also is the most reliable.

### What the plugin does

It jumps in when WP is fully loaded and adds an action/callback function to the `the_post`-hook. There it then checks the globals `$numpages` (holds the number of pages a post has) and `$pages` (holds the parts a post is splitted up by using `<!--nextpost-->` in the content). If the number of pages is not larger than `1`, it aborts. Else it searches through the posts pages for the searched string. If it was found, then it sets the `$link` class property to the page link using `_wp_link_page()`. This link then gets attached inside the filters offered by `get_permalink()`.

### What for does it work?

It works for posts, pages & custom post types

### The plugin

As everytime: Free for use. Grab it, use it. Have fun with it.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (#31913) Search Results - direct link to page
 */

add_action( 'wp', array( 'search_direct_page_links', 'init' ) );

class search_direct_page_links
{
    public static $instance;

    public static $s;

    public $link;

    public static function init()
    {
        is_null( self :: $instance ) AND self:: $instance = new self;
        return self :: $instance;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        if ( ! is_search() )
            return;

        is_null( self :: $s ) AND self :: $s = get_query_var( 's' );

        add_action( 'the_post', array( $this, 'is_paged' ) );
    }

    public function is_paged( $post )
    {
        global $numpages, $pages;

        // reset link:
        $this->link = get_permalink();

        // Remove filters attached from the last post
        foreach ( array( 'post_link', 'page_link', 'post_type_link' ) as $filter )
        {
            remove_filter( $filter, array( $this, 'alter_link' ) );
        }

        if ( 1 >= $numpages )
            return;

        $target = 1;
        foreach ( $pages as $i => $p )
        {
            if ( is_int( strpos( $p, self :: $s ) ) )
            {
                $target = absint( $i ) +1;

                // Get the link now, as _wp_link_page()
                // calls get_permalink() internally,
                // which would lead to an endless nested loop.
                $this->link = str_replace(
                     array( '<a href="', '">' )
                    ,''
                    ,_wp_link_page( $target )
                );
            }
        }

        if ( 1 < $target )
        {
            add_filter( 'post_link', array( $this, 'alter_link' ), 10, 3 );
            add_filter( 'page_link', array( $this, 'alter_link' ), 10, 3 );
            add_filter( 'post_type_link', array( $this, 'alter_link' ), 10, 4 );
        }
    }

    public function alter_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename, $sample )
    {
        return $this->link;
    }
}
```